# How do I get the alignment right for this equation?

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm writing an equation that I want to be aligned roughly like this:

```
-1 ≤   Re z ≤ 1
-2 ≤ 2 Re z ≤ 2
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```latex
\renewcommand{\Re}[1]{\,\mathrm{Re}\,{#1}}

\begin{align*}
-1 \leq & \Re{z}  &\leq 1 \\
-2 \leq & 2\Re{z} &\leq 2
\end{align*}
```

[image: output of the code]

---

How can I get it to look like what I showed?

Comment: use `&&` before the last part so it is left aligned, also please always post a complete document not just a fragment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm, that didn't work for me. I had to use `alignat*` as Werner suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With multiple alignment points within the same construction, it's best to use `alignat` (and friends):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  -1 \leq {}&&  \Re{z} & \leq 1 \\
  -2 \leq {}&& 2\Re{z} & \leq 2
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. By the way, if I want to add a bit more space after the first ≤ should I just use `\;` or something? Currently it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLFNv.png because I overrode the `\Re` command.

Comment: @Camelid: Note the use and location of `{}` in my code.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that `{}` added spacing. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Column pairs in `align` are separated by a wide blank space. You need `alignat`, but it's not really easy to take care of the necessary tricks.

I find it more convenient to use `array` for this application.

Note that your redefinition of `\Re` is not the best.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
-1 &\leq{} &  \Re z &\leq 1 \\
-2 &\leq{} & 2\Re z &\leq 2
\end{alignat*}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}c<{{}} r}
-1 &\leq&  \Re z &\leq& 1 \\
-2 &\leq& 2\Re z &\leq& 2
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `>{{}}c<{{}}` we reserve a column for the relation symbols, suitably spaced because of the empty items around them.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip re `\Re` :)

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "You need alignat, but it's not really easy to take care of the necessary tricks."? I found that it seems to work quite well.

Comment: @Camelid You need to suitably apply `{}` in not easy to predict (for a beginner) places; and controlling the alignment is not easy either; with `array` you have more choices.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think I saw some people say you shouldn't use `array` since it's not semantically correct, but I guess using `alignat` can be annoying enough that `array` is sometimes worth it?

Comment: @Camelid The name `array` doesn't imply matrices are necessarily involved, just alignments.